# api is not displaying serialized json output using alamofire

Tags: json, swift, api, web-services, alamofire

I have created simple login screen attached with loginViewController.swift. i have simple login api.The web service it is showing response on post man web service is not displaying serialized json output on xcode using alamofire.How to get serialize json from url .

```
et url="http://192.169.201.32:9000//users/authenticate"  ?the api is getting two parameters from username ="andrews" and password="admin2".

       let url="http://192.168.100.11:9000//users/authenticate"
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters:["username":"andrews","password":"admin2"], encoding: JSONEncoding.default)
            .responseJSON { response in          
/////is it correct way to enter the parameter??
                print("abcsign in")
                print(response)
                //to get status code
                if let status = response.response?.statusCode {
                    switch(status){
                    case 201:
                        print("example success")
                    default:
                        print("error with response status: \(status)")
                    }
                }
                //to get JSON return value
                if let result = response.result.value {
                    let JSON = result as! NSDictionary
                     print("abcsign in 2")
                    print(JSON)

                }

        }
        [self  .boaderSetting()]


        username_input.text = "andrews"
        password_input.text = "admin2"

        [self .login_now(username:"andrews", password:"admin2")]
        let preferences = UserDefaults.standard
        if preferences.object(forKey: "session") != nil
        {
            login_session = preferences.object(forKey: "session") as! String
            check_session()
        }
        else
        {
            LoginToDo()
        }


    }
```

how to get the serialized json out put on Ns log ?you can download the project from this link .https://drive.google.com/file/d/1h3TMFkpyOdCB_SoLYdca5Jmh4vulL7t_/view?usp=sharing

Comment: change JSONEncoding to URLEncoding

Comment: Please post the result of `response.result`

Comment: print(response.result) . FAILURE error with response status: 404

Answer (score 0):

Uses URLEncoding instead of JSONEncoding will solve your problem

Comment: print(response) responseSerializationFailed(Alamofire.AFError.ResponseSerializationFailureReason.jsonSerializationFailed(Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Invalid value around character 2." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Invalid value around character 2.}))
abcsign in3

Comment: print(response.result) . FAILURE
error with response status: 404